# No pre-built ActionBar for Android pre-3.0?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I note the release a few days ago of the static library bringing fragments to Android versions prior to 3.0, but does this library include the ActionBar? I suspect not.

I assume that for an app that will work on pre-3.0 versions, that it needs a hand-built ActionBar implementation for versions up to 2.3 and then to use the OS default ActionBar in v3.0?

for some reason I assumed the library had ActionBar in it, but as I dig further I'm not finding any evidence of its presence.

Comment: Just wanted to give you a heads up that I have released an extension to the compat library which includes support for emulating the native ActionBar on pre-3.0 devices. Check it out at http://actionbarsherlock.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static library does not contain the ActionBar. Probably because the ActionBar is a window feature and could not properly be added as a static library.

You should fall back to something that most applications use today. Namely the "action bar" that Google uses in their [I/O](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) app for example.

Comment: This ActionBar project has some source that works well https://github.com/markchang/android-actionbar